# How to ask people to be more straightforward?

Tags: europe

Often when I'm talking to people they are simply not straight forward. I don't want to be rude but I don't like it when people beat around the bush. I often say to them something like this:

> Could you come to a point.

Personally I wouldn't like it if someone said this to me. So How can I say to people they should explain themselves quickly when they're beating around the bush.

I'm looking for a strategy to ask those people. The relationship is with those people are mostly stranger. But also teacher and people who I work with.

I live in the center of Europe and I'm 18 years old (m).

Comment: Are you looking specifically for an English phrase (since it is obviously not your first language (neither is it mine)) or are you looking for a strategy in principal? What is your relationship with those people? Family members, strangers on the street, coworkers, your boss, customers, your best friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Personally I wouldn't like it if someone says this to me.

But you clearly also don't like it when they keep going on and on without actually saying/asking what they want. So it's fine if you don't come across as really friendly with that one sentence. Just make sure to react possitively when they actually condence their point after your remark.

On when and how to tell them I would make a difference whether they're trying to ask a question or when it's really just an interesting story that keeps draging on.

## real question

Just interrupt, possibly with something like: "and what is your question?". It's better to interrupt early and do so with a big smile on your face.

It's possible they're trying to ask something where they're afraid of your answer and are just trying to postpone that moment a bit. In this case just "help" them by interrupting with "And what exactly are you asking now?" or something similar. (Again, big smile, possitive mood).

## story telling

Depends a bit on your usual interactions. You may want to let them finish the story and suppress your annoyance. Or you can interrupt shortly with "it's too interesting speed it up a little 'cause I wanne know how it ends!". Try to keep it light hearted so the mood stays possitive.

---

If it happens often you may want to talk with your friend about it taking so long. It **will** be a bit awkward depending on how you word it but if it's a real friend and you show you're still interested in what he has to say, as long as he tries to come to a point faster, then he shouldn't feel too bad about it. In the end it will probably make both of you happier since he can still talk about all his stuff with you while actually getting a better response from you.